# iOS alternative to android's UUID(long mostSigBits, long leastSigBits)

Tags: java, android, ios, uuid

I'm currently creating a iOS version of an existing android app for a client and I have to create a parameter that is created in the android version like this:

`UUID(Long.parseLong(stringA), Long.parseLong(stringB))`

Both stringA and stringB are numernic strings. Is there any way I can replicate java's UUID() in iOS? I don't know what kind of transformations it does to the strings. Any idea?

NOTE: Just to be clear. I'm NOT looking for a way to get an UUID code in iOS. The java function is used in the original app to create an identifier based on the two given strings.

Comment: Do you find any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Swift `universally unique identifier`(UUID)

```
let uuid = UUID().uuidString
```